# Иммитация нажатия мыши на сенсорном экране win10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Суть проблемы такова: есть приложение на WPF, развернутое на сенсорном терминале. В разных местах приложения вызываются окна, принадлежащие к одному классу. В одном конкретном месте программы при вызове такого окна, оно не реагирует на нажатия на сенсорный экран. При этом, если подключить к терминалу мышь и взаимодействовать с окном при помощи неё - все работает нормально, если запустить приложение на ноутбуке с сенсорным экраном (например, Lenovo Yoga), окно отрабатывает корректно. Следовательно, проблема непосредственно в терминале. Калибровка и переустановка драйверов тачпада не помогла. Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему? Вероятно, есть какой-то софт, который эмулирует нажатие мыши или что-то подобное? Спортивное гугление не помогает...

Comment: ээм, а вам не каежтся, что тут вопрос не к WPF ? а если в других приложених в этой области тыкать все норм или как ? эмулировать нажатие конечно можно, но чем вам это поможет непонятно

Comment: @PavelPopov да, в других приложениях в этой области все норм. Эмуляция, вероятно, помогла бы, так как, повторюсь, когда взаимодействуешь с окном при помощи мыши (на том же терминале) - все норм, проблемы только при использовании сенсора, видимо, винда как-то хитро работает с сенсором и мне эта хитрость выходит боком. Вопрос определенно не к WPF, указал это для полноты картины

Comment: Да эмулировать не проблема, по этому делу в сети есть куча инфы. Ну на пример целый инструмент [тут](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator) хотя можно обойтись и просто WinApi только любопытно как вам это поможет ?) как вы его прикрутите ?